# SMS converts to MMS and only sends when data mobile is on

Tags: sms, mms

I have had a Galaxy S2 for 2 years. I just upgraded to the S4 3 weeks ago.

Until this morning, I was able to send SMS messages without data mobile being on via my Wi-Fi connection.  I have made no alterations to my phone other than trying out various suggestions on given on forum sites. I have tried 3-word messages as a test and even these are converted to MMS.

I have loaded both Handcent and Bigsms. They work, but why should I have to have these after 2 years and 3 weeks without a problem?

Comment: See Amit's answer in the link above.

Comment: @user37267, Welcome to StackExchange. Read this page (http://android.stackexchange.com/about) to earn your first badge.

Comment: This might be a different issue than the "possible dupe": there **long SMS** get converted, here even short ones. Rather see [SMS converts to MMS after only one word](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14043/16575) -- which unfortunately has no answer, but the comment over there might prove helpful.

Comment: OK, looks like despite my previous comment, some answers to the linked questions seem to cover this as well :)